# Installed Calico on my 3 Node K8S setup. PODS across nodes are unable to communicate

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed Kubernetes setup on 3 node cluster and deployed calico CNI. All the pods in kube-system are running fine but what i observed that pods created across the nodes are unable to communicate with each other. I am unable to figure out the resolution and struggling on this.

Comment: calico pods are running ? kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: what distribution of k8s are you using? how did you setup your cluster? please provide exact details.